# Dynamic Banner Ad in Website glitches when transitioning to bottom of site

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I have a dynamic banner ad in my website that is having issues. It defaults to the top of the page normally, and when I scroll down past a certain point, the ad is suppose to become fixed at the bottom of the page to remain view-able by the user. This works fine, however if I scroll right to the point where the banner ad gets loaded at the bottom, the entire page and the ad glitches and its a real eye sore. If I scroll a little down or up, the glitching stops.

I tried editing my css file to include the -webkit-transform:transform3d(0,0,0) styling method that has been said to fix this glitch, but even when i commit the file, that line of code is overwritten in the inspector and the glitch remains. Any ideas what this is or how to not have the code overwritten.

Its my first time posting, so if you need additional info, let me know.

Comment: Sounds like the glitch appears because the ad disappears in the absolute document structure so the page goes up again which causes the ad to jump back and so on... Try to use some kind of placeholder with the height of the ad while the ad is fixed. Or just put the ad in a container with a specific size and then only change the position value of the ad.